# Can't access value in my data store using reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm dispatching an action after I query my db for an array of data:

```js
dispatch({
                type: "SET_EDIT_PRODUCTS",
                item: [
                  {
                    name: productData.name,
                    price: productData.price,
                    description: productData.description,
                    quantity: productData.description,
                  },
                ],
              });
```

Here is how the data is stored in my reducer:

```js
export const initialState = {
  editProductBasket: [],
 
};
```

Here is how my case is structured:

```js
case "SET_EDIT_PRODUCT":
      return {
        ...state,
        editProductBasket: [...state.editProductBasket, action.item],
      };
```

Now, when I try to access the `name` property in my `editProductBasket`, I get the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

I think I may be incorrectly destructuring the array when I try to access the property:

```
const [
    {
      editProductBasket: [{ name }],
    },
    dispatch,
  ] = useStateValue();
```

```js
return (
    <div className="phone__mockup">
     {name}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting undefined because there's a mistake in the way you're destructuring the action.item and setting it in the reducer. 
Instead of doing `editProductBasket: [...state.editProductBasket, action.item],`,

try this : 
`editProductBasket: [...state.editProductBasket, ...action.item],`.

You're not destructuring the array coming from `action.item`. Due to this an array is created inside the `editProductBasket` array instead of creating a new object of product details.

Comment: Hey Rajiv, I'm still getting the same error. Is it perhaps due to how I am dispatching an array with an object in it?

Comment: try console logging your store variable 'editProductBasket' after dispatching and check the structure of the data inside it. Is it all objects inside it? Because the issue seems in the process of setting the data in the store

Comment: Looks like my 'editProductBasket' is an empty array although I'm clearly dispatching the action. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: what is `useStateValue` hook?